# How do I Debug this on Android?. Stack Trace from Logcat Below

Tags: android, oauth, twitter4j

This is the entire stacktace from Logcat. I'm basically using the twitter4j library. I've added my tokens and secrets from the twitter dev site. **Can you Help me Debug this?**
The code is mostly based on http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

### Thanks!

```
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659): Process: code.laerstudios.gappa, PID: 12659
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:135)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:122)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:298)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at code.laerstudios.gappa.MainActivity.loginToTwitter(MainActivity.java:225)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at code.laerstudios.gappa.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:212)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at code.laerstudios.gappa.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:153)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-13 16:38:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(12659):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-13 16:38:25.449: I/Process(12659): Sending signal. PID: 12659 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Teach a man to fish;

If you Google the exception you got, you'll notice that you can't run network operation on the main thread.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=NetworkOnMainThreadException&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&oq=NetworkOnMainThreadException&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i59&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: So should I run it on Async? Its confusing because I didn't need to run network tasks on my previous apps... I did see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Yes. In fact, I recommend using a HTTP library like loopj: loopj.com/android-async-http/

Answer (score 0):

The exception at the top is very clear: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Android does not let you do network operations on your main thread. Try creating an `AsyncTask` and do you operations there asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple You have some network related Code in your `UI` thread, So put that within a thread like

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
@Override
public void run() {

}
};

thread.start();
```

Any code related to `Http request` or `socket` or any such things that are network related which will block the UI execution will cause this exception

Comment: I did see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception but this is giving me no head or tail...

Comment: post your code causing this , I think you are trying to log in to twitter in mainthread may be not post your code , So that it will be easier

Comment: is it possible to use theads within a void function?

Comment: Yest you can do it within any method